# How to overwrite with fake data or disable "fingerprinting" by user identifying js object: navigator

Tags: javascript, tracking, tampermonkey, navigator, greasemonkey-4

The [navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) object is used to identify users browsing. Even if you have extensions installs which help block a lot of identifying scripts, it seems that the `navigator` object is always available.

Some identifying characteristics I'd like to feed fake data to (or disable)

```
navigator.geolocation
navigator.plugins
navigator.battery
navigator.oscpu
navigator.platform
navigator.userAgent
navigator.(etc)
```

There was no effect when attempting to overwrite the object using GreaseMonkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: [X-Agent](https://github.com/mrbar42/X-Agent) unofficial extension overrides `navigator`

---

I could not find a way to overwrite the `navigator` object permanently or disable it. However, I came across the [VikingVPN's post](https://vikingvpn.com/cybersecurity-wiki/browser-security/guide-hardening-mozilla-firefox-for-privacy-and-security) and [GHack's post](http://www.ghacks.net/overview-firefox-aboutconfig-security-privacy-preferences/) on hardening Firefox.

1. Open `about:config`
2. Set the following (excerpt)

   - To disable fingerprinting by addon installations set `plugin.scan.plid.all` to `false`
   - To disable location services set `geo.enabled` to `false`
   - To disable battery checks set `dom.battery.enabled` to `false`
3. Install [Stop Fingerprinting](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stop-fingerprinting/) addon for Firefox

Comment: Disable all these things is another way of fingerprinting! The only way is to return different random data each time.

Comment: @joseantgv how would someone go about returning different data when `navigator.x` (where x is anything) is accessed?

Comment: I didn't say that this is possible :) Just that this is not a solution to prevent fingerprinting